# Nontrivial solutions of a set of nonlinear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following set of nonlinear equations

$f_{11}(U)A+f_{12}(U)B+f_{13}(U)A^2+f_{14}(U)B^2+f_{15}(U)AB=0$
$f_{21}(U)A+f_{22}(U)B+f_{23}(U)A^2+f_{24}(U)B^2+f_{25}(U)AB=0$

where $f_{ij}$ are functions of the variable $U$.

In my problem, $A$ and $B$ are small, but non-zero.

An approximate solution for this problem can be found by neglecting the higher order terms: $A^2, B^2, AB$ (since $A$ and $B$ are small). This allows to write:

$f_{11}(U)A+f_{12}(U)B=0$

$f_{21}(U)A+f_{22}(U)B=0$

These equations can be written in matrix format

$\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
f_{11}(U) & f_{12}(U) \\
f_{21}(U) & f_{22}(U)
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
A \\ B \end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$

For non-trivial solutions (non-zero $A$ and $B$), the determinant of this matrix should be zero.

$f_{11}(U) f_{22}(U) - f_{12}(U) f_{21}(U) = 0 $

This can be solved to find the values of $U$ (which is the result of interest in this problem).

My question is how can I solve this problem without neglecting the higher order terms: $A^2, B^2, AB$.

Comment: You could try to use perturbation analysis to determine analytic approximations.

Comment: Do you have any references (or examples) for perturbation analysis is this kind of problem ? Thank you.

Comment: There are great online lectures by Carl Bender on youtube. He has also written a book on perturbation theory.

Comment: The multivariable case was not part of his lectures but i think it should be straigt forward to extend the idea to the multivariable case. Btw as I am on mobile right now I have some trouble with the display of your equations, but have you tried to solve the equations with Maple/sympy in Python/mathematica or other computer algebra systems?

Comment: Thanks. I am already watching one of his videos.

Comment: Actually I have tried to use Maxima. But the program hangs without giving any results.